# Mockito, argThat, and hasEntry

Tags: java, testing, mockito, hamcrest

> tl;dr: These tests don't compile because the type parameters don't match. What changes should I make to make them compile and run
>   correctly?
>
> https://github.com/wesleym/matchertest

I have some non-test code that calls into a service. It calls the service's activate method with a map parameter.

```
public class Foo {
  private final Service service;

  public Foo(Service service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  public void bar() {
    Map<String, ?> params = getParams();
    service.activate(params);
  }

  private Map<String, ?> getParams() {
    // something interesting goes here
  }
}
```

Some code I'm trying to test has a dependency on a service like this one:

```
public interface Service {
  public void activate(Map<String, ?> params);
}
```

I'd like to test this code by mocking the service with Mockito and verifying that activate was called with a reasonable map. The following code works:

```
@Test
public void testExactMap() {
  Service mockService = mock(Service.class);
  Foo foo = new Foo(mockService);

  foo.bar();

  Map<String, String> expectedParams = new HashMap<>();
  expectedParams.put("paramName", "paramValue");
  verify(service).activate(expectedParams);
}
```

However, I'd like to just test that the map contains one particular entry. The Hamcrest [hasEntry matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.0.0.0/) seems perfect for this use case:

```
@Test
public void testHasEntry() {
    Service mockService = mock(Service.class);
    Foo foo = new Foo(mockService);

    foo.bar();

    verify(mockService).activate(argThat(hasEntry("paramName", "paramValue")));
}
```

When I try this, I get the following error in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
Error:(31, 45) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.String,? extends java.lang.String>
    upper bounds: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>,java.lang.Object
```

The problem here is that I need a Mockito matcher of `Map<String, ?>`, but hasEntry gives me a matcher of `Map<? extends String, ? extends String>`. Even with explicit type parameters, I can't figure out what to do to reconcile the "? extends" part of the type parameter. What should I do to resolve this error? Is there a specific cast or explicit type parameter I should use?

*I understand that I can use ArgumentCaptor for this.* Is that really the only way to do this? Is this possible at all with Hamcrest matchers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `argThat` return type is not being inferred for some reason. Try explicitly casting as shown below:

```
 Mockito.verify(foo).bar((Map<String, String>) argThat(Matchers.hasEntry("paramName", "paramValue")));
```

The `testHasEntryCast()` can be fixed as shown below. Notice that cast `(Map<String, ?>)` is to `argThat` return type:

```
@Test
public void testHasEntryCast() {
    Service mockService = mock(Service.class);
    Foo foo = new Foo(mockService);

    foo.bar();

    verify(mockService).activate((Map<String, ?>)  argThat(hasEntry("paramName", "paramValue")));
}
```

Comment: First, I had the wrong code snippet up. Sorry! Corrected now. Second, this doesn't work. Service.activate expects `Map<String, ?>`, but the wildcard is not allowed in the cast. Replacing `?` with `Object` doesn't work either.

Comment: I've added a link to an example project to the question.

Comment: The cast to Map<String, ?> is misplaced in testHasEntryCast(). See my edited answer above.