# Mockito: verify argument is a Map using a regex pattern

Tags: dictionary, groovy, mockito

I have a function that does the following:

```
mock_object.install_tool name:"Python27x32', type:"CustomTool'
```

When testing the function, I want to verify the following:

```
verify(mock_object, times(1)).install_tool(argThat(hasEntry('name')))
verify(mock_object, times(1)).install_tool(argThat(hasValue('Python\\d{2}x\\d{2}')))
```

I am trying to make use of the `matches` Matcher but failing with the following error:

> 1 matchers expected, 2 recorded

What should I do to match a map value by regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: `org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasEntry` requires 2 arguments, 
Your code with only one argument is invalid

```
hasEntry('name') // no such overload
```

`hasEntry` has 2 overloads:

- `hasEntry(K key, V value)`
- `hasEntry(Matcher<? super K> keyMatcher, Matcher<? super V> valueMatcher)`

We want value comparison in key, and regex in the value.
Thus, we use:

- key: `Matchers.is(T value)`
- value: one of

  - `Matchers.matchesPattern(java.lang.String regex)`
  - `Matchers.matchesRegex(java.lang.String regex)`

Unfortunately, in Java we need extra unchecked cast. See [Mockito, argThat, and hasEntry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288390/mockito-argthat-and-hasentry)

We end up with:

```
Matcher<String> mapKeyMatcher = Matchers.is("name");
Matcher<String> mapValueMatcher = Matchers.matchesPattern("Python\\d{2}x\\d{2}");

verify(mock_object, times(1)).install_tool(
        (Map<String, String>) argThat(
                hasEntry(mapKeyMatcher, mapValueMatcher)
        )
);
```

**Update on Hamcrest**

Mockito comes with its own set of matchers: `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers` but unfortunately it does not have Map matchers. Luckily Hamcrest does, and this is why you used Hamcrest in the first place.

To adapt Hamcrest matcher to Mockito matcher you use `argThat(YOUR_HAMCREST_MATCHER)`

The map matcher we decided to use has following signature:

```
hasEntry(Matcher<? super K> keyMatcher, Matcher<? super V> valueMatcher)
```

Both arguments are Hamcrest matchers. You cannot pass regex matcher from Mockito, you need to use Hamcrest one.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this. I came accross the `matches` function and couldn't use it. How is it used ?

Comment: I can't really tell without knowing which class it belongs to. `java.util.regex.Matcher`? It is a totally different Matcher. You cannot pass it to methods expecting Hamcrest Matcher

Comment: It is `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.matches`

Comment: Thanks so much for the explaination